# Find the area of ​a regular pentagon as a function of its diagonal

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

For reference:

> Calculate the area of ​​a regular pentagon
> as a function of its diagonal of length $a$. (Answer:$\frac{a^2}{4}\sqrt\frac{25-5\sqrt5}{2}$)

My progress:

[image]

$R$ = radius inscribed circle

$S = \frac{5R^2}{8}(\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})$

$L=\frac{R}{2}(\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5})\implies R^2 = \frac{4L^2}{10-2\sqrt5}\tag{I}$

$\cos36^\circ=\frac{a}{2L} \implies a = L(\frac{1+\sqrt5)}{2}\implies L= \frac{2a}{1+\sqrt5}$

$\implies L^2 = \frac{a^2}{4}(6-2\sqrt5)\tag{II}$

$\text{From (I)}: S = \frac{20L^2}{8(10-2\sqrt5)}.(\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})$

$\implies S =\frac{5L^2}{2(10-2\sqrt5)}.(\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})$

$\text{From (II)}: S = \frac{5a^2(6-2\sqrt5)}{8.(10-2\sqrt5)}\cdot(\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})$

$S = \frac{a^2(5-\sqrt5)}{16}(\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})$

$\boxed{S = \frac{a^2}{4} \sqrt{\frac{25-5\sqrt5}{2} }}$

Comment: The given answer seems incorrect. In your work, the last step does not seem right. where you are taking $5 - \sqrt5$ inside the square root. In the final answer if $~\frac{a^2}{4}~$ is outside the square root, it should be $~\frac{25 - 5 \sqrt5}{2} ~$ inside the square root.

Comment: Agree with @MathLover, the answer does not seem right. Also, $L\cdot \cos36^{\circ}=\frac{a}{2} \ne \frac{a}{4}$

Comment: @MathLover you're correct...but even so the answer doesn't match...see figure

Comment: @petaarantes:  $\cos 36=\frac{a}{4L}$ is incorrect

Comment: @petaarantes I am not sure what you mean. $2$ in the denominator should be inside the square root if you do the last step correctly.

Comment: How did you derive the first formula?

Comment: @user $S=\frac{5}{2}R^2.sen72 = 5\frac{R^2}{2}.\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}{4}=\frac{5R^2}{8}(\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})$

Comment: @MathLover I reviewed the calculations and now the area is correct. The answer given by the book was really wrong

Comment: @petaarantes yes the book's answer is definitely wrong as I mentioned earlier

Comment: Don't you need to evaluate $\sin 72^°$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are starting with a formula for the pentagon in terms of $R$, you can derive directly as follows -

Given $a$ is diagonal,

$ \displaystyle S_{AED} = S_{BCD}  = \frac 12 \cdot a \cdot \frac {a \tan36^0}{2}$

$ \displaystyle S_{ADB} = \frac 12 \cdot a^2 \sin36^\circ$

So, $~ \displaystyle S = \frac{a^2}{2} \sin 36^\circ \cdot \frac{1 + \cos36^\circ}{\cos36^\circ}$

As $\cos 36^\circ = \dfrac{1 + \sqrt5}{4}$

$ \displaystyle \sin 36^\circ = \sqrt{1 - \frac{6+2 \sqrt5}{16}} = \frac 12 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}}$

Also, $\dfrac{1 + \cos36^\circ}{\cos36^\circ} = \dfrac{5 + \sqrt5}{1 + \sqrt5} = \sqrt5$

So, $ \displaystyle S = \frac{a^2}{4} \sqrt{\frac{25-5\sqrt5}{2}}$

Comment: Its true..verygood..